# Redirect ngnix with params

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I want to config redirect with nginx.conf by this following role:

1. If **device_id** just use id for sub url with another host url
2. If **device_id** & **user_id** change params to **deviceId** & **userId**

   https://host1/tv/view/?device_id=xxx -> https://host2/device/xxx/tv

   https://host1/tv/view/?device_id=xxx&user_id=*** -> https://host2/device/user/tv?deviceId=xxx&userId=***

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you